# openssl_csr_get_public_key in Python

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, rsa

Can anybody suggest any **python** **ssl rsa library** , which has a function like in PHP (**openssl_csr_get_public_key**).

Because i have a certificate , with which i need to verify the data . And every time i try to use this certificate with **M2Crypto** *public key functiton* , it gives error "no start line " , which is completely understandable because its not a public key , but a certificate which has a public key in it. As much as i understand.

Thx in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is [`M2Crypto.X509.load_cert()`](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.X509-module.html#load_cert), and then getting the public key from the certificate object using `cert.get_pubkey()`.

Comment: Yeah. Thx .Thats exactly what i needed. One last question would be great if u could help.  Now that i signed string with private_key , and loaded certificate_request , and got public key , i want to verify that i was the one who signed the string , so i do : `csr.verify_init()  csr.verify_update(StringSignature.encode('base64')) csr.verify_final()` 

What signature do i have to pass to verify_final ? What exactly is signature ? I thought all you need to verify the string is public key 0_O.   Thx Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Oh LOL.... I just understood that i kind of said :D a stupid thing ... I guess i should have passed the string i encoded to  update() method , and StringSignature in base64 to verify_final() ....